# angular firebase parse array to list

Tags: json, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i try to parse an array from Firebase RealTimeDataBase in Angular and want to show it in a list.

The json look like this

```
{
  "users":[
     {
        "id":1,
        "name":"max",
        "email":"max@hotmail.com"
     },
     {
        "id":2,
        "name":"moritz",
        "email":"moritz@hotmail.com"
     }
  ]
}
```

my firebase servic.ts

```
GetNotificationUsers() {
    return this.db.object(this.customerId + "/mailservice/users");
  }
```

my component.ts

```
ipport....

@Component({
  selector: 'app-iot-device',
  templateUrl: './iot-device.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./iot-device.component.css']
})
export class IotDeviceComponent implements OnInit {
 
  notificationUsers : users[];
  
  constructor(private firebase: FireBase) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getNotificationUsers();
  }

  getNotificationUsers() {
    this.firebase.GetNotificationUsers().snapshotChanges().subscribe((data) => {
      let a = data.payload.toJSON();
      this.notificationUsers = a as users[];
      console.log(this.notificationUsers)
    });
  }
}
```

user interface

```
export interface users {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
```

my component.html

```
 <table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Mailaddresse</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of notificationUsers">
      <th scope="row">{{user?.id}}</th>
      <td>{{user?.name}}</td>
      <td>{{user?.email}}</td>
     <tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is the error message...
core.mjs:6362 ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe?

Thanks

Console log
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are console logging the firebase data.  Can you share an example of it?

Comment: i had updatet my post with the console log message

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to iterate an object and not an array.  Try changing this part. The array is in the users property of the JSON.

```
getNotificationUsers() {
    this.firebase.GetNotificationUsers().snapshotChanges().subscribe((data) => {
      let a = data.payload;
      this.notificationUsers = a.users as users[];
      console.log(this.notificationUsers)
    });
}
```

Comment: i try this but i get an error  "error TS2339: Property 'users' does not exist on type 'Object'"